# compilation errors ...even if code is right

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
create or replace trigger t2
    after insert or delete or update
    on emp_salary_details
    for each row
begin
    if inserting then
        insert into emp_table_audit
        values
        ( :new.emp_id
        , null
        , user
        , systimestamp
        , ‘INSERTION’ );

    elsif deleting then
        insert into emp_table_audit
        values
        ( null
        , :old.emp_id
        , user
        , systimestamp
        , ‘DELETION’ );

    elsif updating then
        insert into emp_table_audit
        values
        ( :new.emp_id
        , :old.emp_id
        , user
        , systimestamp
        , ‘UPDATION’ );
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the way, there is no such word as [_'Updation'_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:updation). The word is ['Update'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/update).

Answer (score 3):

Problem seems to be in a "fancy" single quote you use in all actions, for example

```
‘INSERTION’
```

If you look at what it really is (just first two characters):

```
select dump('‘I') from dual;
```

The result shows

```
Typ=96 Len=4: 226,128,152,73
```

- 226, 128, 152 represent that "fancy" single quote
- 73 is a capital letter "I"

Once you replace it with a "normal" single quote, everything should be just fine. Actually, seeing how old this question is, I hope you fixed it already, but a little bit of *debugging technique* can't hurt much.